# Share dynamically updated variables between Python classes

Tags: python, global-variables

I am building a dashboard that will be used to query and plot data. My requirement is that a new query can be made from the running dashboard, which should update the data variable. When the new data is updated the plotting machinery should have access to the updated data and hence plot the results of the last query.

I have 3 classes:
 0. `Dashboard` class that stores instances of the following two classes.
 1. plot figures using `Plotter` class and 
 2. update data using the `Query` class

The code below defines a `Dashboard` class which will

Updating happens on the dashboard GUI so the data to be plotted will be dynamically modified and the plotting class is required to "know" these changes.

```
import numpy as np
global data
data = None


class Query():
    def __init__(self):
        self.blabla = 12
    def get_me_data(self):
        global data
        data = np.random.rand(1)


class Plotter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.line = 3
    def plot_me_data(self):
        print(data)

class Dashboard():
    def __init__(self,glob):        
        self.q = Query()
        self.plotter = Plotter()

    def get_new_data(self):
        self.q.get_me_data()

    def plot_me_data(self):
        self.plotter.plot_me_data()
```

The code above uses one single module where all classes are defined. And it defines at the top of the hierarchy the global `data` variable that both `query` and `plot_me_data` instances will be have the updated version of the data.

The code below shows how calling `get_me_data` method from `Query` instance updates the data and that this data is accessible from `Plotter` instance method.

```
print(data) #returns None
#
a = Dashboard(12) 
#
print(data) #returns None
#
a.plotter.plot_me_data() #returns None

a.q.get_me_data() 
a.plotter.plot_me_data() #returns a random number

a.q.get_me_data()
a.plotter.plot_me_data() #returns another random number
```

So far so good. This is the rookie solution and it does the job.

I am not really sure but I think it would be wiser to have individual modules for each class and import those modules from the `Dashboard` module. So basically I would like to split this 3 class definitions into three different modules.

With this in mind, I create three modules:

```
#./Dashboard.py
import Query
import Plotter
class Dashboard():
    def __init__(self,glob):
        global data
        data = None
        self.q = Query.Query()
        self.plotter = Plotter.Plotter()

    def get_new_data(self):
        self.q.get_me_data()

    def plot_data(self):
        self.plotter.plot_me_data()
```

```
#./Plotter.py
class Plotter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.line = 3
    def plot_me_data(self):
        global data
        print(data)
```

```
#./Query.py
import numpy as np

class Query():
    def __init__(self):
        self.blabla = 12
    def get_me_data(self):
        global data
        data = np.random.rand(1)
```

Running the following code:

```
import Dashboard;
a=Dashboard.Dashboard(12);
a.plot_data()
```

I would have expected `None` to be returned but I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/sonat/Documents/repos/surge_dashboard/surge_dashboard/Dashboard.py", line 14, in plot_data
    self.plotter.plot_me_data()
  File "/Users/sonat/Documents/repos/surge_dashboard/surge_dashboard/Plotter.py", line 6, in plot_me_data
    print(data)
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Why? Well I was naively thinking that `data` variables would be connected to each other across multiple modules and class instances.

I would really appreciate to hear about how to deal the best way with this type use cases...

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard to not use global variables. Since Dashboard hosts everything, it should have self.data and pass it into the other objects it creates.

Comment: I agree with quamrana on avoiding globals.
Having Dashboard trigger an update in Plotter when Dashboard gets new data could be as simple as having an onUpdate in Plotter and calling it from Dashboard when it receives new data, either passing the data along or passing self.
This is kind of a question of architecture. So it might be worth looking at some design patterns and having a think about how your code should be structured.

Comment: thanks people for your comments. I solved the problem passing the dashboard self to dashboard's subcomponents and letting them update self.data... This worked pretty well.